# Need help getting rid of space CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to divide my web page in to four equal parts. I had found some tips online that said to do the following:

```
html,body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

The problem is when I do this I have black space to the right of each picture that I want to get rid of. I tried getting rid of the float left but then the page was not divide into 4 parts anymore. How would I get it so each div with a picture is filled completely with the picture?

```css
body {
 background-color: black;

}
.next {
 color: #995c00;
 vertical-align: center;
}

h1 {
 color: #995c00;
 font-family: Garamond  ;
 font-size: 50px;
 text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
 h2 {
 color: #995c00;
 font-family: Garamond;
}
ul {
 color: #995c00;
 font-family: Garamond;
}

/*body {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}*/
.result-section{
 color: #995c00;
 font-family: Garamond  ;
}
html, body { height: 100%; min-height:100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

#div1 {width:50%; 
        height:50%;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        
        
        }

#div2 { background-image: url(pictures/drums.jpg); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:contain;
        width:50%; 
        height:50%;
         float:left;
         position:relative;
         

        
        
    }

#div3 { background-image: url(pictures/keyboard.jpg); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:contain;
        width:50%; 
        height:50%;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        
         
        
       }

#div4 { background-image: url(pictures/mixer_2.jpg); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:contain;
        width:50%; 
        height:50%;
       float:left;
        position:relative;
       
         
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <TITLE>2016 Grammy Quiz</TITLE>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
   <div id = 'container'>
   <h1> 2016 Grammy Quiz</h1> 

        <h2 id='questionTitle'> </h2>
        <ul id ='selectionList'> </ul>

        
        <button type="button" class = 'next'> Next </button>
      
    <section class="result-section" style="display: none;">
        <h2 class="text"> Final Score </h2>
        <h3 class="text" id="finalScore">10/10</h3>
        <div id="result_msg"></div>
        <button class="start-button" id="tryagain">Try Again</button>
    </section>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
</div>
<div id="div3"> 
</div>
<div id="div4">
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pls update your code & add images that are showing blank space. I'll work on it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your code with images hosted online so we can see what you're seeing. With what you've posted, it's not possible to tell if the background images are the issue or your floated DIVs. Also, it would be good to know what OS and browser you're seeing this issue on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to accomplish something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/49gg12nr/2/

`background-size:100% 100%;`

Seems to be what you are missing

Edit: Updated link

Edit2: Updated Link (again), removed the old *background-size: contain;*
It may help to read up on the differences between **contain** and **100% 100%**. From the link below, you can see that *contain* does just that, it makes it so that the image will be contained within the container, but it keeps proportions the same. *100% 100%* causes the image to fill the container, but ignores proportions. You can't have both, unless you set the container to be of consistent proportions.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp